# alertview textField returning empty string

Tags: swift, uialertview, uialertviewcontroller

```
class x: UIViewController {

    let fromLocationLbl = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let editTextField = UITextField()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Please enter from location", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField { editTextField in
            editTextField.placeholder = "Enter correct name"
            // editTextField.text = self.fromLocationLbl.text
        }

        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            print(editTextField.text) ///////printing optional("")
            self.fromLocationLbl.text = editTextField.text
        }

        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: i want to assign text field test to label, but it is returning empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editTextField` isn't the same `UITextField` as you're adding to alert. In `addTextField` closure, `editTextField` is just name for parameter of closure which can be replaced with any other name

```
alertController.addTextField { textField in
    textField.placeholder = "Enter correct name"
    // textField.text = self.fromLocationLbl.text
}
```

You need to get reference for first text field in your `alertController`

```
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change", style: .default) { _ in
    self.fromLocationLbl.text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
}
```